# Replicate data-toggle="collapse" without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins

I am using some Bootstrap code with

```
data-toggle="collapse"
```

Which uses their jQuery plugin Collapse, and needs jQuery to work. I won't be using much JavaScript, and I do not want the 100k that jQuery comes with, just for this one function.  Is there a light way to replicate this function?  I looked through the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) but there is little on how to replicate.

I tried dropping in some jQuery lite alternatives - Zepto, xui, cash  (although some of these look pretty old) - and they aren't working with the plugin out of the box.

Is there a jQuery lite alternative that will work with this plugin? Or can I replicate the functionality - I am guessing it can be done in a much smaller package than needing jQuery?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your code? so we can help and understand a bit better

Comment: @wilsotobianco not really needed on this on actually

Comment: @Jon Have a look at the [actual source code for the collapse plugin here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/collapse.js) that's where I would start. That should be more helpful than the Docs for you purpose

Comment: Its the data-toggle="collapse" function that comes with bootstrap.  There are code examples in the link - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: @DelightedD0D  thanks for the link to the code , but Im not really well versed enough to tell what it needs in jquery, so I can take the rest out...

Comment: Actually, have a look at [Bootstrap Navbar without jQuery](https://mpetroff.net/2015/03/bootstrap-navbar-without-jquery/) seems like **exactly**  what you need. [They have a demo here too](http://bl.ocks.org/mpetroff/raw/4666657beeb85754611f/)

Comment: Thats a great find - thanks.  If you make it an answer I can accept